# Can i get all the folders and files (under all level) inside a main folder using CAML

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml-query, caml

I have the following CAML query where i am trying to get all the files and folders that are directly and indirectly added to the folder named `FolderA`:-

```
camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem6 = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs").GetItems(camlQuery6);
context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
      item => item.Id,
      item=>item["FileDirRef"],
      item => item["Title"],
      item => item["DealStage"]));
```

the above CAML will only return the main folder under `/sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA`, but will not return any of the sub-folders and files.. so can anyone advice how i need to modify the CAML, or CAML does not support this?

Comment: Are you executing this from a CSOM app?

Comment: @willman yes specifically inside a remote event receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is only returning items directly in that folder because your CAML is set to only return items where the `FileDirRef` (or Folder Path) is equal to `/sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA`, anything that is in a subfolder would have a different `FileDirRef`, such as  `/sites/projects/ArchDocs/FolderA/SubFolder1`, which would not be **equal** to the path you specified.  What you want to do, is instead of the `<Eq>` operator element, you want to use `<BeginsWith>`.  Note, you also appear to have syntax error with your string concatenation `context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA"</Value>`

Give this a try:

```
camlQuery6.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/FolderA" + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";
ListItemCollection collListItem6 = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs").GetItems(camlQuery6);
context.Load(collListItem6, items => items.Include(
      item => item.Id,
      item=>item["FileDirRef"],
      item => item["Title"],
      item => item["DealStage"]));
```

Comment: ok worked well for me thanks, but all the docs i read used <Eq> instead of <BeginWith>.. thanks